# How to configure Hibernate to use DBCP2 Connection Pooling?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

I'm developing a Webapp using Tomcat and Hibernate. After upload and start the application my server's log return this message:

> ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper- The last packet successfully received from the server was 193,600 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 193,601 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Many similar questions about this problem said i require to use a connection pool like c3p0 or DBCP to solve it. I decided to use DBCP2 and added commons-dbcp2 and commons-pool2 as dependencies in Maven following many recommendations from internet examples. For some reason, official [DBCP documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) offers no examples at the moment.

Also added the following lines in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://server.org:3306/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

    <!-- Mapping -->

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Besides, i still receive this message in my server log when restarted:

> WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl- HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool [not for production use!]

Surely i'm doing something wrong. But as DBCP documentation offers no examples. I'm unable to find what must be done to correct it.

I really appreciate if anybody could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of **commons-dbcp2** and **commons-pool2** are you using? You should not have to specify **commons-pool2** in the pom as it will be included as part of **commons-dbcp2**.

You may have a dependency issue by declaring **commons-pool2** with a different version of the **commons-pool2** included with **commons-dbcp2**.